# Bootstrap 3 columns beside each other?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

**I'm trying to make a grid of responsive images using bootstrap 3, but when i try to put them together, one beside one using the code below the last 2 columns goes away down from the other columns :**

[image]

### **This is what i try to achieve :**

[image]

**HTML :**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img class="img" src="path/to/image" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.row { overflow:hidden; }
.img { min-width:100%; max-width:100%; min-height:100%; max-height:100%; }
.col-md-3 { min-height:100%; max-height:100%; }
```

**NOTE :** if i set the max-min/height-width by pixels and i resized the window the columns overlapping each other, so i've to set it by percentage! and still not getting the result that i want.

will appreciate any help.

Comment: in your wish pic there's same height but in your result pic that's not same height... right???

Comment: Yup, the wish pic i've set the height by pixels but the columns overlapping eachother when i resize the window, and in the result pic i've set the height by percentage so the result is'nt what i want. @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal

Comment: This is normal behavior with floated elements. Do you want a jQuery or css solution?

Comment: any of them but if there's a css solution why jquey? @Christina

Comment: a script can tuck the columns/boxes like bricks (masonry) CSS (without using flexbox) can't.

Comment: Any solution, ANY! even if php @Christina

Comment: do you want exactly the wish picture div and img height,then its easy

Comment: I mean equal height for all div??

Comment: .img { min-width:100%; max-width:100%; min-height:100%; max-height:100%; }
.col-md-3 { min-height:100%; max-height:100%; } 
you need to add the height in PX not in %

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way to do it by converting the grid, in this instance only, to `inline-block`. That is the css and html below. Another way is to use a script that sets up the grid like masonry blocks that tuck under each other, you can use jscripts like masonry, mason, isotope, shuffle and a number of other scripts. Here's an example of shuffle https://jsbin.com/vaquci/2

### DEMO: https://jsbin.com/rurap/1/

*https://jsbin.com/rurap/1/edit?html,css,output*

[image]

**CSS**

```
/* demo */
.col-sm-4 {border:1px solid red;}
.well {height:200px;}
.height1 {height:250px}
.height2 {height:300px}
/* demo */


@media (min-width:768px) {
    .inline-block-row {
        word-spacing: -1em;
        letter-spacing: -1em;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .inline-block-row .col-sm-4 {
        word-spacing: normal;
        vertical-align: top;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        display: inline-block;
        float:none;
    }
}
@media (min-width:992px) {
    .inline-block-row .col-md-3 {
        float:none;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <h1>Inline Block Grid</h1>
   <div class="row inline-block-row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
         <div class="well height1">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
         <div class="well">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
         <div class="well">3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
         <div class="well"> 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
         <div class="well"> 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
         <div class="well height2"> 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
         <div class="well"> 7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
         <div class="well height1"> 7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
         <div class="well"> 7</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're an awesome person! now i'm gonna modifiy all my projects using this way, thanks alot for the help :) appreciated ♥

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="path/to/image" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="path/to/image" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="path/to/image" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="path/to/image" />
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="path/to/image" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="path/to/image" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="path/to/image" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="path/to/image" />
        </div>

    </div>
    ... more rows
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.row > div {
   padding-bottom: 30%; // This will give height 
}
```

Comment: i can't set row div more than 1 time because i'm retrieving one row div frorm the database,
thnx 4 the help anyway.

Comment: I add `img-responsive` class to the img it will make image responsive, and `padding: 20%;` will make it total responsive.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need that all boxes have the same height, you should try to use Mansory plugin http://desandro.github.io/masonry/. It's the best plugin for this type of grid.
But if you need that all boxes have the same height. You can get the highest height and set for all boxes. Like that:

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 item">
            <img class="img src="path/to/image" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

var highestH = 0;
var height = 0;
$('.container-fluid .item').removeAttr('style');
    $('.container-fluid .item').each(function () {
        // verify highest height
        height = $(this).outerHeight();
        if (height > highestH) {
            highestH = height;
        }
        height = highestH;

    });
    $('.container-fluid .item').outerHeight(height);
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually can solve this issue very simply, without any custom CSS and only minor changes to your HTML. 2 ways actually.

1 - You can put each row of cols into it's own `<div class="row">`:

2 - Or throw a `<div class="clearfix"></div>` after the last item of each row (not `.row`), or combine it with the `hidden/visible` helper classes if #1 messes with your responsive layout.

http://www.bootply.com/yC3nVhlb64

Comment: i can't place the clearfix div after e.x 4 columns because i'm retrieving the columns from the database so they are dynamic if i put a clearfix it will be placed after every column, so evey column will be alone in one line. but it's a good solution if not using database, thanks for the help Shawn i really appreciate your help.